# How do I solve the following initial value problem using the method of characteristics?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, characteristics, transport-equation

I'm starting to learn about the method of characteristics and tried the problem below, but ran into some problems:

$\begin{align*} v_t + \sin^2(x)v_x &= 0, \ t > 0, \ x \in(-\pi, \pi)\\
v(x,0) &= g(x) \end{align*}$

$v, g$ are continuously differentiable functions in all variables.

Consider the ODE

$\begin{align*} X'(t) &= \sin^2(x), \ x \in (-\pi,\pi)\\
X(0) &= x_0 \end{align*}$.

The solution is $X(t) = \sin^2(x)t + c$, where $c$ is a constant.

Since $X(0) = x_0 = 0 + c$, we get $x_0 = c$.

Further, we can check that $v$ is constant along the characteristic curves $(X(t),t)$ defined by the solutions of the ODE above. Thus,

$v(X(t),t) = v(x_0,0) = g(x_0)$.

We have that $x_0 = x - \sin^2(x)t$, hence $v(x,t) = g(x_0) = g(x-\sin^2(x)t)$.

My problem is that, when I try to differentiate the solution, I can't get the result to satisfy the original DE. Also, I'm not used to working on an interval such as $(-\pi, \pi)$, but rather on all of $\mathbb{R}$. Perhaps I need to specify the solution as a piecewise defined function, somehow?

Comment: The characteristics are incorrect: they satisfy $X' = \sin^2(X)$.

Comment: @EditPiAf So $X'(t) = \sin^2(X(t))$, hence $X(t) = -\cot^{-1}(c + t)$? How can I then get an expression for $x_0$? Sorry for my confusion.

Comment: Setting $t=0$ gives you $X(0) = x_0 = -\cot^{-1}(c)$, so that $X(t) = -\cot^{-1}(t - \cot (x_0))$ or equivalently $x_0 = \cot^{-1} (t + \cot X(t))$. Final solution reads $v = g(x_0)$ along the curves $x = X(t)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$v_t+\sin^2(x) v_x=0$$
The Charpit-Lagrange system of characteristic ODEs is :
$$\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{\sin^2(x)}=\frac{dv}{0}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{\sin^2(x)}$

$t=\int\frac{dx}{\sin^2(x)}=-\cot(x)+$constant.
$$t+\cot(x)=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from finite $\frac{dv}{0}\implies dv=0$
$$v=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE expressed on the form of implicite equation $\Phi(c_1,c_2)=0$ is :
$$\Phi(t+\cot(x)\:,\:v)=0$$
where $\Phi$ is an arbitrary function of two variables,

or equivalently on explicite form :
$$v=F\big(t+\cot(x)\big)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function, to be determined according to an initial condition.

Condition : $v(x,0)=g(x)$ with a given function $g$.

$v(x,0)=F\big(0+\cot(x)\big)=g(x)$
$$F\big(\cot(x)\big)=g(x)$$

Let $X=\cot(x)\quad\implies\quad x=\cot^{-1}(X)$
$$F(X)=g\big(\cot^{-1}(X)\big)$$
Now the function $F$ is determined. We put it into the above general solution where $X=t+\cot(x)$ and $F\big(t+\cot(x)\big)=g\big(\cot^{-1}(t+\cot(x))\big) $

This leads to the particular solution which satisfies the initial condition :

$$v(x,t)=g\big(\cot^{-1}(t+\cot(x))\big)$$